# cannot install ubuntu 20.04 server on virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 server on VirtualBox 6.1 but it keeps crashing.  It complains about

```
/dev/loop2 Can't open blockdev
```

and

```
failed unmounting /cdrom
```

It also complained about something related to one file being bad.  I've downloaded the ISO twice.

I don't have HyperV turned on in windows 10.

[image]

[image]

[image: HyperV turned off in windows:]

Here are my bios settings:

[image: bios]
[image: bios]
[image: bios]

Comment: I've never enabled HyperV in windows but have not checked the bios.  Should i turn that off in the bios?

Comment: Why are you people asking about Hyper-V, the author's problem, is due to the fact VirtualBox is unable to mount a virtual cd-rom from the ISO.  *My educated guess is that the file is corrupt*  **This has absolutely nothing to do with Hyper-V**

Comment: I have tried 2 different downloads of ubuntu 20.04.  I've tried ubuntu 18 and it also is hanging with a different issue entirely.

Comment: I updated my bios from a12 to a29.  I restarted my machine successfully and started up virtualbox.  It says "focal main restricted.  Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in the set" and the same blockdev error.  Never mentions the /CDROM.  Also hangs with ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The bios settings for virtualization settings were turned on.  Trusted execution is not.  I added screenshots.

Comment: The mounting error is in your screenshot.

Comment: sure, the unmount error but why would it happen w/ multiple downloads w/ Ubuntu 20?

Comment: @fregas Never solved this?

Comment: having exact same problem on a macos host...

Comment: sha check sum says that the disk is OK

Comment: downgraded virtualbox to 6.0 and could install ubuntu server. so I assume its a virtualbox problem

Comment: @mohamnag Same issue here! And I downgraded just like you and it worked. Thanks bud :)

Comment: Exact symptoms replicated on bare Dell Precision TR5400 hardware today.  Unfortunately, cannot downgrade to resolve as non-install storage media are blank.

Comment: Same on macOS 10.15.1, Vbox 6.1.14, when installing ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso/  Downgrade to Vbox 6.0.24, and all is good despite "/dev/loop2 Can't open blockdev" message.  VMware Fusion or Parallels is worth the commercial license cost.  VMware just works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
(PC: Windows 10 (20h2), CPU Athlon x250, 4gb RAM, GTX 650ti; Windows 10 features or components - default (Hyper-V isn't installed))

**Settings which worked for me:**

1. Settings > System > Motherboard  : *Chipset choose ICH9;
   enable "Enable I/O APIC";
   enable "Hardware CLock in UTC Time"*.

[image: pic of Motherboard tab]

2. Settings > Processor : *1 cpu;
   enable "Enable PAE/NX".*

[image: pic of Processor tab]

3. Settings > System > Acceleration  : *paravirtualization interface - Hyper-V;
   both boxes checked in hardware virtualization.*
   (have no idea why it works, cause Hyper-V isnt installed on the Windows)

[image: pic of Acceleration tab]

All other parameters are by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to uncheck the virtual machine platform in Turn Windows features on-off. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, go to the audio section of the settings and uncheck the Enable Audio option.

[image: Here's an image on what to do]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove the ISO file.
Remove it by going to **Storage** panel and Remove it from **Controller.**