# Cannot install CentOS nor Ubuntu on HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I've attempted to install CentOS Steam 8 and Ubuntu 20.04 as of right now, and each time I try to install them, it gives me the same error and doesn't work.
The error that it gives me is: `/dev/loop2 Can't open blockdev`, and after about 10-30 seconds it gives another error: `failed unmounting /cdrom` and then it just stays in that state and does nothing. After 120 seconds it times out and won't really do anything else. I'm not really sure what this problem is, I have already searched, and found a thread about the same issue that I have ([cannot install ubuntu 20.04 server on virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/1559234/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-server-on-virtualbox)), however that is in a virtual machine, and this is on real hardware, so I'm really unsure about what to do, how would I fix this?

Comment: Are you installing from CD? Why not use a USB device with the latest version of CentOS or Ubuntu?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am already using a USB drive, with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, I asked because of the error, `failed unmounting /cdrom`. Perhaps in BIOS, disable CDROM on boot? Or the message could be specious.